# Loopback 4 cron / scheduled tasks

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I would like to run scheduled tasks for my Loopback 4 API. I can set up scheduled tasks using node quite easily using packages such as node-cron or node-schedule.

**My question is where and how should I implement this code within my Loopback 4 API?**

My idea is to write a Custom Booter which will discover and run the cron logic when the Loopback API "boots". However not sure if I'm going down the correct path here.
https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Booting-an-Application.html#custom-booters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had exactly the same task and did it the way you described, i.e. we initialize our [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) based tasks in the boot scripts. It works really well.

There are some things you may need to consider when you tasks in Node.js:

- If you plan to run multiple instances of your Node app (for instance with pm2 or something else), you may need to make sure your tasks would only run on one primary node rather then on all the nodes at the same time. If a primary node fails, the next node must be selected as a new primary. Depending on the business logic, it may not be a problem in your case. In our case it was mandatory and we managed to implement it using advisory locks in PG (we used combination of pg_try_advisory_xact_lock and pg_advisory_xact_lock)
- You may want to implement an option to stop/start the tasks as well as to see its statuses via Loopback API/Loopback Explorer. We made a few custom API methods in Loopback to do exactly that and found it very useful

> My question is where and how should I implement this code within my
>   Loopback 4 API?

So, the answer is go ahead and implement it the way you proposed. You can initialize your tasks in a custom booter. You should also consider the points I mentioned above depending on your business needs.

Answer (score 0):

### This solution has worked for me.

#### Installation

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron
$ npm install --save node-cron
```

#### Create a component

```
import { CronController } from "./controller/cron.controller";
const cron = require('node-cron');

export class Cron {
  constructor(
    protected cronController: CronController,
  ) {
  }

  async start() {
    this.eachMinute();
  }

  private async eachMinute() {
    console.log('Start Cron Jobs');

    cron.schedule('* * * * *', async () => {
      await this.cronController.start();
      console.log('running a task every minute');
    });
  }
}
```

#### Using Loopback DI Container to get a controller instance:

```
// index.ts
export async function main(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
  const app = new MyApplication(options);
  await app.boot();
  await app.start();

  const url = app.restServer.url;
  console.log(`Server is running at ${url}`);
  console.log(`Try ${url}/ping`);

  // Instanciate CronController
  const cronController = app.controller(CronController);

  // Get Instance
  const cronControllerInstance = await cronController.getValue(app);

  // Inject by constructor
  const cron = new Cron(cronControllerInstance);

  // Invoke method
  cron.start();

  return app;
}
```

Original Answer https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/4047#issuecomment-523637653